# Is there a way to combine several different conditionals with a shared statement?

Tags: c, syntax, logic, structure, conditional-statements

Is there a way to combine several different conditionals with a shared statement?

For example:

```
int a;
...
if (a == 1){
    foo;
    ...
    return K1;
}
else if (a == 2){
    foo;
    ...
    return K2;
}
...
else if (a == i){
    foo;
    ...
    return Ki;
}
```

Is there a smart way to take `foo` out but make it happen only under these conditionals? (Like factoring in algebra: 2x+6=2(x+3)).

It feels repetitive so I figure there should be way to make it shorter.

Comment: Could you do `foo; return array[i];` ?

Comment: @WeatherVane that's a nice idea actually but the returned value isn't always stored in an array.

Comment: If there's a simple way to combine the conditions into one (for example, `1 <= a && a <= i`), you could have one `if (combined_condition) {foo;}` before the big else-if chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this be OK in your scenario?

```
int a;
int k; // let's assume int
...
k = a == 1? K1:
    a == 2? K2:
    ...
    a == i? Ki:
    K0; // a special value
if (k != K0)
    foo;
return k;
```

Comment: Way smarter solution than mine :D

Comment: It really depends on heaviness of "..." blocks in original post.

Comment: @user3125367 Yes, and it also depends if we have a continuous sequence 1,2,...,`i` or anything else.

Comment: @user3125367 Because if we assume that we have the sequence, then an array can be used, as others suggested.

Comment: Oh, that depends on pureness and lightness of K* then :)

Comment: I saw this nested `?` operation in some code a few weeks ago and didn't get it, nor why did they have to use something so unreadable, but now it all makes sense, it's pretty cool actually.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming return value is of type `int` (change it accordingly). You can use following:

```
int a;
int retVal;
int execFoo;

execFoo = 0;
...
if (a == 1){
    execFoo = 1;
    ...
    retVal = K1;
}
else if (a == 2){
    execFoo = 1;
    ...
    retVal = K2;
}
...
else if (a == i){
    execFoo = 1;
    ...
    retVal = Ki;
}

if(execFoo == 1)
    foo;
return retVal;
```

Comment: IMO, this feels as repetitive as the original code.

Comment: @Unda It may be fixed with execfoo = 1 before ifs and reset it once in else-block. That doesn't solve the issue with foo being called *after* other blocks, though.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on WeatherVane's comment about an array - the values *can* always be stored in an array, even if they didn't reach the block in question that way - just put them in a new one:

```
T array[] = { [1] = K1, K2, K3, ..., Ki };
foo();
return a <= i && a > 0 ? array[a] : K0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to use a helper function to get `k` corresponding to `a` and then use the value of `k` to call `foo` or not.

```
// Function to get K given a.
int getK(int a)
{
   switch (a)
   {
      case 1:
         return K1;

      case 2:
         return K2;

      default:
         return K_Unknown;
   }
}
```

Use of the function:

```
int a;
int k = getK(a);
if ( k != K_Unknown )
   foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may #define a macro `IF(cond) if ((cond) && (<foo>, 1))` and #undef it after all blocks:

```
#define IF...
IF (a == 1) { ... }
else IF (a == 2) { ... }
#undef IF
```

(provided `<foo>` is a single expression)